Nextjs Authentication not throwing error on the login page
This is my login page submit function:
const handleSignIn = async () => {
    console.log("Attempting login..."); // Debugging line
    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    console.log("Result received:", result); // Debugging line

    if (result?.error) {
      console.error("Login failed:", result.error);
    } else {
      console.log("Login successful:", result);
    }
};

This is my app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:
import { handlers } from '@/auth';

export const { GET, POST } = handlers

This is my credentialsProvider file in the auth.ts file at the root folder:
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { graphqlAuthApi } from "./redux/services/auth/graphqlAuthApi";
import { store } from "./redux/store"; // Make sure to import your store properly

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "example@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (
          !credentials ||
          typeof credentials.email !== "string" ||
          typeof credentials.password !== "string"
        ) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        try {
          console.log("Attempting login...");

          // Dispatch the login action and unwrap to access the response
          const response = await store
            .dispatch(
              graphqlAuthApi.endpoints.login.initiate({
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password,
              })
            )
            .unwrap(); // Unwrap the payload

          console.log("Response received:", response);

          // Handle successful login
          if (response?.data?.login?.success) {
            return {
              user: response.data.login.user,
              token: response.data.login.token,
            };
          } else {
            throw new Error(response?.data?.login?.message || "Invalid login");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Login failed:", error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});

And this is my graphql endpoint calling using rtk:
import { baseQuery } from './baseQuery';

import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

import { ChangePasswordInput, ChangePasswordResponse, ForgotPasswordResponse, LoginInput, LoginResponse, RegisterationInitateInput, RegistrationInitiateResponse, VerifyRegisterationInput, VerifyRegistrationResponse } from './auth'


export const graphqlAuthApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'graphqlAuthApi',
  baseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    initiateRegistration: builder.mutation<
      RegistrationInitiateResponse, 
      RegisterationInitateInput
    >({
      query: (input) => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation InitiateRegistration($input: RegistrationInitiateInput!) {
              initiateRegistration(input: $input) {
                message
                status {
                  status
                  message
                  email
                  createdAt
                  attemptsRemaining
                  expiresIn
                }
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: { input }
        }
      })
    }),

    verifyRegistration: builder.mutation<
      VerifyRegistrationResponse, 
      VerifyRegisterationInput
    >({
      query: ({ email, otp }) => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation VerifyRegistration($email: String!, $otp: String!) {
              verifyRegistration(email: $email, otp: $otp) {
                user {
                  id
                  email
                  isActive
                }
                token {
                  accessToken
                  refreshToken
                }
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: { email, otp }
        }
      })
    }),

    login: builder.mutation<LoginResponse, LoginInput>({
      query: (input) => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation Login($input: LoginInput!) {
              login(input: $input) {
                success
                message
                user {
                  id
                  email
                  role
                  isVerified
                }
                token {
                  accessToken
                  refreshToken
                }
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: { input }
        }
      })
    }),

    forgotPassword: builder.mutation<
      ForgotPasswordResponse, 
      { email: string }
    >({
      query: ({ email }) => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation ForgotPassword($email: String!) {
              forgotPassword(email: $email) {
                success
                message
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: { email }
        }
      })
    }),

    changePassword: builder.mutation<
      ChangePasswordResponse , 
      ChangePasswordInput
    >({
      query: (input) => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation ChangePassword($input: ChangePasswordInput!) {
              changePassword(input: $input) {
                success
                message
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: { input }
        }
      })
    }),

    logout: builder.mutation<{ success: boolean }, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          query: `
            mutation Logout {
              logout {
                success
              }
            }
          `
        }
      })
    })
  })
})

export const { 
  useInitiateRegistrationMutation,
  useVerifyRegistrationMutation,
  useLoginMutation,
  useForgotPasswordMutation,
  useChangePasswordMutation,
  useLogoutMutation
} = graphqlAuthApi

My problem is I'm getting an error like this when I am calling the sign in method:
enter code here
enter image description here

in the backend im getting calls and showing response user not found
